# Trying to get some information next to a form in HTML-CSS

Tags: html, css

So I'm making a page in HTML with a form and some information. I made 2 classes, one for the form which is called .contactform in CSS, and one for the information which is called .contactinformatie in CSS.

I want to place the information next to the form but it isn't working.
This is how my page looks (As you can see the information goes under right to the form and not next right to the form:

https://gyazo.com/d2b6619b6abece882559243fb42e7fd6

How can I fix this?

These are my HTML codes:

```
<div class="contactform">
<h3> Uw gegevens: </h3>
<form action="">
     Naam*<br>
    <input type="text" name="Naam" value="Tom">
    <br><br>
     Email adres*<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="tom@gmail.com">
    <br><br>
     Telefoonnummer<br>
    <input type="text" name="telefoonnummer" value="020-694-2033">
    <br><br>
     Uw vraag<br>
    <textarea id="txtarea" rows="10" cols="70" value="Hoe kan ik een vluchtnummer toevoegen?"></textarea>

    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Versturen">
</form>
</div>

<div class="contactinformatie">
    <p>U kunt 24 uur per dag telefonisch contact met ons opnemen </p>  <p>020-5 160 160</p>
    <br>


    <p>Email: </p> <p>test@hva.nl</p>
    <br><br><p>Adres: </p> <p>Wibautstraat 44</p>

</div>
```

And these are my CSS codes:

```
.contactinformatie {
     float:right;
     margin: auto;
     width: 48%;
     height: 50%;
 }

.contactform {
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

So how do I get the information next to the form in CSS?

Comment: If you want to use float, put the contactinformatie div above the form in the source. If you put it underneath, it will not move itself up to sit next to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using flexbox see below snippet i have wrapped your **contactform** and **contactinformatie** div's into **container** and set `.container {
  :flex`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.contactinformatie,
.contactform {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="contactform">
    <h3> Uw gegevens: </h3>
    <form action="">
      Naam*<br>
      <input type="text" name="Naam" value="Tom">
      <br><br> Email adres*<br>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="tom@gmail.com">
      <br><br> Telefoonnummer
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="telefoonnummer" value="020-694-2033">
      <br><br> Uw vraag<br>
      <textarea id="txtarea" rows="10" cols="70" value="Hoe kan ik een vluchtnummer toevoegen?"></textarea>

      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Versturen">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="contactinformatie">
    <p>U kunt 24 uur per dag telefonisch contact met ons opnemen </p>
    <p>020-5 160 160</p>
    <br>


    <p>Email: </p>
    <p>test@hva.nl</p>
    <br><br>
    <p>Adres: </p>
    <p>Wibautstraat 44</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use floats on both contactform & contactinformatie classes. Remember to clear float after these 2 elements.

```
.contactform, 
.contactinformatie {
  width: 50%;
  float: left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'display: inline-block' to all the wrapping elements that need to be placed in a row

```
.contactinformatie {
  display: inline-block; 
  margin: auto;
  width: 48%;
  height: 50%;
}

.contactform {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 80px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 max-width: calc(100% - 48% - 50px)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is that one of your div elements is set to float, while the other does not handle the output of this behavior. You would need to set both to float if you'd like to have the expected output.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.contactinformatie {
  padding: 50px;
  float:right;
  width: 50%;
 }

.contactform {
  padding: 50px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Here is a codepen that shows everything together:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yRgZXG

Answer (score 0):

```css
.contactinformatie {
     margin-left: 50px;
     width: 48%;
     height: 50%;
 }

.contactform {
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactform">
<h3> Uw gegevens: </h3>
<form action="">
     Naam*<br>
    <input type="text" name="Naam" value="Tom">
    <br><br>
     Email adres*<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="tom@gmail.com">
    <br><br>
     Telefoonnummer<br>
    <input type="text" name="telefoonnummer" value="020-694-2033">
    <br><br>
     Uw vraag<br>
    <textarea id="txtarea" rows="10" cols="70" value="Hoe kan ik een vluchtnummer toevoegen?"></textarea>

    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Versturen">
</form>
</div>

<div class="contactinformatie">
    <p>U kunt 24 uur per dag telefonisch contact met ons opnemen </p>  <p>020-5 160 160</p>
    <br>
    <p>Email: </p> <p>test@hva.nl</p>
    <br><br><p>Adres: </p> <p>Wibautstraat 44</p>
</div>
```

Chech the above code.